# Generalized integer casting in Python

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

#### Background

I have a string in Python which I want to convert to an integer. Normally, I would just use `int`:

```
>>> int("123")
123
```

Unfortunately, this method is not very robust, as it only accepts strings that match `-?[0-9]+` (after removing any leading or trailing whitespace). For example, it can't handle input with a decimal point:

```
>>> int("123.45")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123.45'
```

And it *certainly* can't handle this:

```
>>> int("123abc?!")
```

On the other hand, exactly this behavior can be had without any fuss in Perl, PHP, and even the humble QBasic:

```
INT(VAL("123abc"))   ' 123
```

#### Question

Here's my shortest effort at this "generalized `int`" in Python. It's 50 bytes, assuming that the original string is in `s` and the result should end up in `i`:

```
n="";i=0
for c in s:
 n+=c
 try:i=int(n)
 except:0
```

Fairly straightforward, but the `try`/`except` bit is ugly and long. Is there any way to shorten it?

#### Details

Answers need to do all of the following:

- Start with a string in `s`; end with its integer value in `i`.
- The integer is the first run of digits in the string. Everything after that is ignored, including other digits if they come after non-digits.
- Leading zeros in the input are valid.
- Any string that does not start with a valid integer has a value of `0`.

The following features are *preferred*, though not required:

- A single `-` sign immediately before the digits makes the integer negative.
- Ignores whitespace before and after the number.
- Works equally well in Python 2 or 3.

(Note: my code above meets all of these criteria.)

#### Test cases

```
"0123"   -> 123
"123abc" -> 123
"123.45" -> 123
"abc123" -> 0
"-123"   -> -123 (or 0 if negatives not handled)
"-1-2"   -> -1 (or 0 if negatives not handled)
"--1"    -> 0
""       -> 0
```

Comment: Somewhat related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28783/implement-an-integer-parser (but there it was explicitly stated that input would be properly-formed integers).

Comment: What should `"12abc3"` give?

Comment: @orlp `12`--it's analogous to the `"123.45"` case.

Comment: `(lambda(x)(or(parse-integer x :junk-allowed t)0))` (Common Lisp, 49 bytes) -- Only posted as a comment since it is built-in.

Comment: @coredump `:junk-allowed`--ha, that's great!  I would have made this a general golf challenge, were it not for the fact that the answer in many languages is trivial.  But thanks for the Lisp.  :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 40 bytes

```py
import re;i=int("0"+re.split("\D",s)[0])
```

and you can do negatives for 8 characters more:

```py
import re;i=int((re.findall("^-?\d+",s)+[0])[0])
```

Comment: @DLosc Ah you're right, didn't test the second one well enough apparently. The 'aha' moment was when I realized some python regex functions return strings not MatchObjects

Comment: `import re;i=int((re.findall("^-?\d+",s)+[0])[0])` works, for 48 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Python <s>2, 47</s>, 46

It's not as short as using regex, but I thought it was entertainingly obscure.

```
i=int(('0%sx'%s)[:~len(s.lstrip(str(1<<68)))])
```

-1 due to KSab – `str` with some large integer works better than the repr operator since it does not put an `L` on the end.

Comment: you can shave off a byte by using `str(1<<68)` inside the lstrip

Comment: Wow.  Entertainingly obscure is right!  (This only handles nonnegative numbers, correct?)

Comment: Another bonus of @KSab's suggestion is Python 3 compatibility.